# Converting CAD Annotation to Shapefile with attributes using FME?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, annotation

What transformer should I use to add AutoCAD Mtext to GIS attribute table using FME?

The reader file in CAD and I want to transform it to GIS Shapefile. In this case I want to expose the attribute from text (fme_text_string) to DC_LAND_PARCEL_BOUNDARY(polygon geometry). 
So how to expose the attribute along with the value, so that in ArcGIS i only turn on the labeling options to show the annotation.

Comment: Does it have to be a shapefile? - you will get better results with converting cad annotation to file geodatabase annotation.

Comment: Is FME your only software option? I suggest autocad map.  I can script it and run it on multiple drawings with perfect results. And with fme enabled on map it will write any format just like fme.

Comment: yes..it have to be shapefile..but i want to convert cad annotation to the attribute table..the cad annotation that belong to the certain feature layer (for example road) are assign in attribute table of the layer road in GIS.

Answer (score 2):

First add the Autocad annotation layer in ArcGIS.
Open the table of this layer and write down the fields you want to have in your shapefile.

Now create a point shapefile and add the same fields.
Start editing the shapefile and just copy-paste the autocad annotation in the shapefile.

The table in the shapefile should now contain the text displayed in the annotation so now you can just label the points in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

For arcgis the solution is to [convert the Annotation to points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) and then [Spatial join them](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to the parcels.

Comment: Please explain your answer in detail

Comment: how about using FME?any solution?